# Getting Run-time error '424': object required

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to add a custom header for each specific sheets whether the cell "H13" on "DonotPrint - Setup" sheet is empty. If found empty it will just add a default text. While if its not empty, it will copy over "H13" value and add it to the header.

Note: this code is written within "DonotPrint - Setup" sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim headerSheets As Variant, sh
    Dim Filename As String
    headerSheets = Array("COVER", "SCOPE", "SUMMARY", "Updated Hours EST", "RATES")

    If IsEmpty(Me.Range("H13").value) Then
    Filename = "Proposal Template"
    headerSheets.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&B &12 PROPOSAL" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & " &08 " & Filename
    Else
    Filename = .Range("H13")
    headerSheets.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&B &12 PROPOSAL" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & " &08 " & Filename
    End If
End Sub
```

But I am getting Run-time error '424': object required when doing this and its highlighting the second code line after the "Else".

Comment: What is `.Range("H13")` referring to? What is the value of `Filename` after that line?

Comment: `headerSheets` is an array of strings, not objects you can call methods on.

Comment: Looks like the misqualified `.Range("H13")` in the `Else` block needs to be `Me.Range("H13")`

Comment: @BrianMStafford Bingo! Post that as an answer, get some rep for it!

Comment: The `headerSheets` variable is not an object, it's an array. I think you want to use the name of the sheet (each sheet?) as in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(headerSheets(1)).PageSetup ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `headerSheets` variable is defined as a variant, containing an array of strings.  As such, it is not an object you can call methods on.

You want to iterate the array of sheet names, and for each sheet name, get the `Worksheet` object with that name.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(headerSheets) To UBound(headerSheets)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(headerSheets(i))

    'now you have a Worksheet object to make member calls against:
    ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "..."
    '...
Next
```

Comment: OTOH, it's something OP can *iterate* with a loop :-)

Comment: @BrianMStafford hmm... so how can you group those sheets then

Comment: Look at the comment from @MathieuGuindon above (and his edit).

Comment: @GoldFusion see edit. Alternatively, you can get a `Sheets` collection by passing the array of sheet names to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`, e.g. `Set theSheets = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(headerSheets)`, and then you have a collection of `Worksheet` objects that can be iterated with a `For Each` loop.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon what is this LBound(headerSheets) To UBound(headerSheets) for?

Comment: @GoldFusion you have an array, you want to loop through that array. LBound gives you the lower boundary, UBound the upper boundary - never assume what array boundaries are.